# Remove spaces between tags in an html file in vim

Tags: vim, html

I have a badly formatted html file that I am editing.

In several places, there is unnecessary space between tags. See below for example:

```
<b>   Bold Text   </b>
```

I want to remove this extra space to get:

```
<b>Bold Text</b>
```

But I am not able to generate the Search and Replace pattern to take care of all the possibilities viz:

```
<b>**Bold_Text**</b>
<b>**Bold_Text**</b>__normal_text__<em>**Emphasised_Text**</em>
<ul><li>**Bullet**</li><li>**Bullet**</li></ul>
```

Note: * indicates space that needs to be removed and _ space that needs to be retained.

`\(<.\{-}>\)\s\+\(\S\+.*\)\s\+<` search string falters in case 2 and it removes the space around normal text. I need to group the elements so I can use them in replace.

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is a bad idea. Consider using something like Tidy (see example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14764401/2072269) to format HTML instead.

Comment: it's much of answer by itself. You could post what you did as an answer though, and it would make a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I could find was to use `tidy` to clean the file up and then use:
`:%s/<b>\s*/<b>` and several such commands in a macro